# Reverse database records flask

Tags: python, flask

I was looking about how to display some records from a database on a html table and I came across of this question.
[Python displaying SQLite3 database records on a Flask local website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258703/python-displaying-sqlite3-database-records-on-a-flask-local-website)

Everything great until now. I managed to display the records etc. But in order my records to be accurate I have to reverse the order of the listing and display just the latest 30 records of the database. Have you got any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL to order the records and limit how many are returned:

```
cur = g.db.execute(''''
    SELECT * from Recipe_tbl
    ORDER BY some_column DESC
    LIMIT 30
    ''')
```

You do need to define what 'latest' means in this case.

For example, if you are using SQLite's [`AUTOINCREMENT` columns](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) then the primary key can be used to track insertion order; ordering by that column in descending order gives you the most recent record on top.